# Fastlane deliver fails with deleting screenshots

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I'm setting up fastlane deliver and can't figure out why it keeps failing to upload screenshots. Well, it appears to fail when it tries to delete the existing ones? I'd like to force upload new ones if possible.

Fwiw, if I comment out the screenshots lane, the app itself uploads perfectly fine.

Any help is appreciated to be honest. There isn't much online about this issue.

Output:

```
[13:08:34]: Making sure the latest version on App Store Connect matches '2.1.0'...
[13:08:34]: '2.1.0' is the latest version on App Store Connect
[13:08:34]: Detected languages: ["en-US", "default"]
[13:08:38]: Will begin uploading metadata for '2.1.0' on App Store Connect
[13:08:38]: Release type will not be set because neither `automatic_release` nor `auto_release_date` were provided. Please explicitly set one of these options if you need a release type set
[13:08:38]: Uploading metadata to App Store Connect for version
[13:08:42]: Uploading metadata to App Store Connect for localized version 'en-US'
[13:08:44]: Uploading app review information to App Store Connect
[13:08:45]: Setting the app's age rating...
[13:08:46]: Will begin uploading snapshots for '2.1.0' on App Store Connect
[13:08:46]: Starting with the upload of screenshots...
[13:08:47]: Number of screenshots not deleted: 12
[13:08:47]: Failed to delete all screenshots... Tries remaining: 4
[13:08:47]: Number of screenshots not deleted: 12
[13:08:47]: Failed to delete all screenshots... Tries remaining: 3
[13:08:48]: Number of screenshots not deleted: 12
[13:08:48]: Failed to delete all screenshots... Tries remaining: 2
[13:08:48]: Number of screenshots not deleted: 12
[13:08:48]: Failed to delete all screenshots... Tries remaining: 1
[13:08:49]: Number of screenshots not deleted: 12
```

Lane:

```
lane :send_to_app_store do |options|
        deliver(
            api_key: api_key(options),
            username: options[:username] || ENV["FASTLANE_USER"],
            team_name: options[:team_name] || ENV["FASTLANE_TEAM_NAME"],
            app_identifier: options[:bundle_id] || bundle_identifier,
            screenshots_path: options[:screenshots_path] || ENV["SCREENSHOTS_PATH"] || "./screenshots",
            skip_screenshots: options[:skip_screenshots] || false,
            overwrite_screenshots: options[:overwrite_screenshots] || ENV["OVERWRITE_SCREENSHOTS"] || true,
            metadata_path: options[:metadata_path] || ENV["METADATA_PATH"] || "./metadata",
            skip_metadata: options[:skip_metadata] || false,
            languages: [
                "en-US"
            ],
            ignore_language_directory_validation: true,
            force: true,
            price_tier: 0,
            app_review_information: {
                first_name: 'John',
                last_name: 'DOH!',
                phone_number: '+555-555-5555',
                email_address: 'john@DOH.com'
            },
            release_notes: { 
                "default" => "Blah blahhh blahhhhh"
                },
            app_rating_config_path: options[:rating_path] || "fastlane/itunes_rating_config.json",
            submission_information: {
                add_id_info_uses_idfa: false,
                export_compliance_uses_encryption: true,
                export_compliance_is_exempt: true,
                content_rights_has_rights: true,
                content_rights_contains_third_party_content: false,
            },
            submit_for_review: options[:submit_for_review] || false,
        )
    end
```

Dir structure:

```
fastlane/screenshots/en-US/screenshots*.png
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. Any solution?

Comment: Old ticket, but first thing that comes to mind: are the images the correct width and height? Apple has strict rules about these.

Comment: I have the same problem and my images are of the right size and names (for the iPad Pro 3rd gen)